# How can I detect the device language in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin

I have created a mobile Xamarin PCL project.

I'm trying to detect if the phone (iOS or Android) is in Italian or not.
I have tried this code but I always receive a return value of "en", even though the phone is set to Italian. (Tested on iOS)

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToString()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName
```

Is the correct way to test for this. However, there's apparently a bug in iOS.

The workaround described here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59596#c8 is to edit your `info.plist` file to add/modify the following:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>it</string>
</array>
```

Add an item for each language your app supports. The example above has English (en) and Italian (it).

Then, you can also add the following key to specify the default language:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>it</string>
```